# Calling Variables

Tags: vba, variables

Can I call variables from outside the Public Sub which was defined in in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather basic-level stuff, but if you don't know what to search for, it can be hard to know how to find the information. This should get you started.

---

You don't "call" variables, you "call" procedures. A variable that's declared with the `Dim` keyword inside a procedure scope, is *local* to that scope it's declared in, so no.

This is best observed with `Option Explicit` specified.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test1()
    Dim foo As Long
End Sub

Public Sub Test2()
    foo = 42 ' illegal: variable is not declared / not accessible in this scope
End Sub
```

The concept to understand here, is *scoping*. Use `Dim` to declare *local variables*. As the name says, such variables only exist in the scope they're declared in.

Next you have *module scope*. You can use the `Dim` keyword *outside of a procedure scope, at the top of the module* for this, but for consistency it's probably a better idea to use the `Private` keyword.

```
Option Explicit
Private foo As Long

Public Sub Test1()
    foo = 42
End Sub

Public Sub Test2()
    MsgBox foo
End Sub
```

This code will compile, and if `Test1` is invoked before `Test2`, the `Test2` call will pop `42` in a message box.

Then you have *public scope*, aka "global". You can use the obsolete `Global` keyword for those, but for consistency it's better to use the `Public` keyword.

```
Option Explicit
Public foo As Long

Public Sub Test1()
    foo = 42
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test2()
    MsgBox foo
End Sub
```

The above will do exactly the same as the previous snippet, except now we have the two procedures in separate modules (*standard* modules - it's important). And the code will compile and run.

---

Rule of thumb, you don't need to declare global variables.

Variables should always be scoped as tightly as possible, and passed around as *parameters*. Parameters can be passed by value (`ByVal`) or, by reference (`ByRef`). If unspecified, `ByRef` is the [unfortunate] default.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim foo As Long
    Assign foo
    MsgBox foo
End Sub

Private Sub Assign(ByVal bar As Long)
    bar = 42
End Sub
```

Running `Test` will pop a message box saying `0`, because `ByVal` passes *a copy* of the value (or a copy of the *pointer* to the object reference, when we're talking about objects).

Contrast with:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim foo As Long
    Assign foo
    MsgBox foo
End Sub

Private Sub Assign(ByRef bar As Long) ' or implicit: (bar As Long)
    bar = 42
End Sub
```

This will pop a message box saying `42`, because `ByRef` passes a pointer to the value (or in the case of object references, the pointer itself). Note that this is usually not behavior you want to allow, hence most parameters should be passed by value.